# org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class com.org.locator.ServiceLocator, class java.lang.Object]

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, java-17

My Project has the following dependencies -:

- implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.4.0'
- implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:5.2.0'
- implementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.14.5'
- implementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.14.5'
- implementation 'org.objenesis:objenesis:3.3'
- implementation 'org.objenesis:objenesis-test:3.3'

We are using ***Gradle*** and ***Spring 5.3.20***

This is the line that's throwing the error -
`try (MockedStatic locatorMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocator.class)){`

Full Stacktrace -:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.org.locator.ServiceLocator.

If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please open an issue on GitHub.


Java               : 17
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 17.0.6+9-LTS-190
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 17.0.6+9-LTS-190
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0


You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class com.org.locator.ServiceLocator, class java.lang.Object]
    at com.saba.unittest.bframework.TestAttachmentServiceImpl.setup(TestAttachmentServiceImpl.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class com.saba.locator.ServiceLocator, class java.lang.Object]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Byte Buddy could not instrument all classes within the mock's type hierarchy

This problem should never occur for javac-compiled classes. This problem has been observed for classes that are:
 - Compiled by older versions of scalac
 - Classes that are part of the Android distribution
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:285)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:218)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.lambda$mockClass$0(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:47)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:40)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:396)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.doCreateMock(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:355)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:334)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:88)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:2087)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:28)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:44)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:72)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:47)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:81)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:184)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.OpenedClassReader.of(OpenedClassReader.java:82)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:3390)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1930)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:207)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.make(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:116)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3397)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.transform(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:402)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:169)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:281)
    ... 69 more
```

I even tried Invalidating the Cache and restarting but am still facing the error "Mockito cannot mock this class"

Comment: The actual cause is "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61". You are using a Java 17-compiled class with something older.

Comment: It turned out there is an internal dependency of asm in byte buddy which is compiled using Java 5 but that is put by default in it, I tried running the same composition of libraries on my local project it works fine but it throws this error on my organisation's project.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, there was an additional bundled library in the project positioned ahead of our library in the sequence in gradle.properties. This library contained an older version of byte-buddy, which was the cause of the problem with the class file's major version as that version was being picked. The issue was resolved by updating byte-buddy to align with our version.

Comment: In my case, it was resolved after adding to my build.gradle

    implementation("net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.14.2")

- Spring: 2.3.2.RELEASE
- Java 11